# Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Date>' - Angular 6+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I am attempting to make a simple clock in Angular, but I cannot seem to get the Observable/Subscription working.

It keeps throwing the error:

> Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'Observable'

Am I missing something here?

**clock.service.ts**

```
export class ClockService {

  private clock: Observable<Date>;

  constructor() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.clock = new Date();
    }, 1000);
  }

  getCurrentTime() {
    return this.clock;
  }
}
```

**clock.component.ts**

```
export class ClockComponent implements OnInit {

  private time;

  constructor(private clockService: ClockService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.time = this.clockService.getCurrentTime.subscribe;
  }

}
```

Comment: You've declared click of type `Observable<Date>`, but you're trying to assign `new Date`, which is not an `Observable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to return observable:

```
this.clock = Observable.interval(1000).map(() => new Date());
```

working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-observable-interval-r5o4r6)

**Update** for **rxjs 6+**:

you should import this way:

```
import { Observable , interval} from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

and use interval this way:

```
this.clock = interval(1000).pipe(map(() => new Date());
```

working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-pipe-g8nkke)

Comment: My IDE doesn't like the .interval() on Observable... `Property interval doesn't exist on type 'typeof Observable`

Comment: which version of rxjs?

Comment: 6.0.0 - I literally did `ng new clock-app`, so it's exactly how the CLI downloaded it. Could probably do with checking for updates on the CLI

Comment: Ah awesome! Thanks for taking the time :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a custom observable that returns a date when you subscribed:

```
export class ClockService {

  private clock;

  constructor() {
    // create observable
    this.clock = new Observable((observer) => {        
    // observable execution
    observer.next(setInterval(() => new Date(), 1000);)
    });
  }

  getClock() {
    return this.clock;
  }
}
```

---

Usage of service:

```
export class ClockComponent implements OnInit {

  private time;

  constructor(private clockService: ClockService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.time = this.clockService.getClock.subscribe((date) => this.time = 
  date.getCurrentTime);
  }

}
```

Note: I didn't try the code so if there is a typo or variable type problem please correct me.